# Access images in component library

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a Angular 7 component library and I am trying to add some images for buttons and the like.

My project structure looks like this

```
projects
 components
   src
     lib
       myComponent
         assets
            images
               image.png
```

The component that I am trying to use the image in is at the same level as the "assests" folder.

For instance I've added this button

```
<p>
<button (click)="activateSelect()"><i 
src="../../assets/images/tempImage.png"></i></button>  
</p>
```

...but when I build and use dev tools in Chrome to look at the button the path to the image is
http://localhost/assets/images/tempImage.png

Seems like routing isn't working correctly for this?

I've tried relative paths, "./", just putting the path in and nothing is working.  This seems harder than it should be so I'm sure I'm not understanding something about how this works.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I never got an image to work on a button but I replaced the "button" tag with an "img" tag and got it to work like this...

```
<img style="background-color: aliceblue;width:35px;height:35px" 
(click)="activateSelect()" src="assets/tempSelect.png">
```

**UPDATE 2**
The above works if you want the images in the "assets" folder of your application.  I am building a component library that I need my assets to travel along with...is there a way to make a folder with assets in a component library that you can build and expose with the component library?

**UPDATE 3**
In order to get your images into your component library so that everything is self contained you will need to use a tool to base 64 encode your images.
I used https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image
Once in the tool select your image and then pick the "Output Format"
I used "Data URI -- data:content/type;base64" 
Then click the "Encode image to base 64" button 
This will output a string like this

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAABTElEQVRIie2WwY2DMBBFX1YpICVQQkpwCSmBk+dKCSmB69wogRIowSW4BDpgDx4kFIEwISG7Ur7kAxqL5+/5Bp+GYeAT+vkI9Qv+s2ARqQ8Hi4gDylfBtzgugBpwIlIeDQ6AA+4icj0K7ICgqj1QAo2IXI4AF6oaAVS1AxobbwfH6YOq1kAvIve3gS3RcaZUATervx4MXOfAD/0u3gEugG6uoKqB5LzdErZdjifwFmhJ5zxPwzCsDu99zJzXee/LnLnntYXZ9i26FZHG6sEc1yISrAWLWgWTtjlMFlEDlQUL0oelsnmFLaIihW43ONqRaYDeYK3VO6BX1XvGuzaDLyQHN5KrR7BjIfVLykl1gbm0vo2gUY/PecpJ4Ex6g/f+sjX103F65nprl4FIaoGzXXHjTyRHOT2eU0NKbgeUW4CjnnL8Cv2PW+YXvEe/8QAaBBU+rp8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

As you can see the above is a "png" image be sure that this property matches the type of image you are using.

Once you have this string you can set a variable to it in your component and add this accessor to the element you want your image in

```
 [src]="YourImageVariable"
```

This will not work with a button since [src] isn't a know property of button but it can be used with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the library component doesn't have project root so it always fetches assets from main project root i.e. assets folder where we are consuming library.

so either you have to use base64 data URL or CDN images.

you can encode images to base64 data URL and use them like

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,...">
```

or bound to a component property

```
<img [src]="imageFoo">
```

Comment: Where does the image live?  Can it be packaged with the Component Library?

Comment: Okay this is the answer but it isn't the full answer...the full answer is that first you need to use a tool to base 64 encode your image, I used https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image - then you can set a variable to the "data:URI" (this is the type that needs to be selected before encoding) like <img [src]="imageFoo">  and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I used `../../../assets/images/icon/multi-y-axis-20x20.png`

You use `..` to go up parent folder.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this.  I used the intellisence built into VSCode to pick the file and it still doesn't show.

Comment: Did you try add more ../ in you path?

Comment: yes, I've tried everything... and the path when observed in Chrome Dev Tools resolves to the base application (test harness) not the component library

Answer (score 0):

As you said, why didn't you store your images in src/asset directory? It should work. I see you have an asset folder in the component folder, so is this the same for other components?
Anyway, if you want angular serve assets that stored outside src/asset, you have to tell angular you did that or angular will see it is a routing url instead of an image url

in angular.json, look for

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

add your own asset folder here

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/lib/myComponent/assets"
],
```

Comment: This is editing a file outside of the component library so the change will not be included when the component library is installed.  I did try it however and it did not work.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
src="assets/images/tempImage.png"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This worked however it did not work with a <button> I could not get an image to work with a button in Angular 7 but what I did get to work was an <img> tag with a (clicK) action on it.

Comment: I thought this worked (and it did if I want to put my images in the application)  I don't want to put the images for my component library in the applications assets folder...I want an assets folder that travels with my component library where I can access images...this is NOT working.  any ideas about this?